# Spring boot oauth: unsupported grant type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, postman

please help me... unsupported grant type makes me crazy..
my spring boot settings look like this.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.configure(endpoints);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            security
            /*.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")*/
              .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("foo")
            .secret("{noop}bar")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token","client_credentials")

            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")

            .scopes("read", "write","trust","openid")

            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.

            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.


        }

    }
```

and this is result of postman test that always return unsupported grant type 'password'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWmSE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwQ2w.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you are using **grant_type="password"**, you have to :

create below bean in your own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
   return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

inject it to `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` class

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

use it in `configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)` method

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
   endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

**Complete Example :**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("a").password("123456").authorities("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
         security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")         
                 .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()") 
                 .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("CLIEN_ID").secret("CLIENT_SECRET")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("CLIENT")
                .scopes("read");
    }
}
```

**Test :**

```
curl -i -X POST -d "username=a&password=123456&grant_type=password&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the input user is valid, could you please try sending client id and client secret params in addition to username, password and grant type.

```
curl http://{host}:{port}/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password -d client_id=client -d client_secret=secret
```

Comment: Stop spamming low quality answer about anything related to security.